# Optimize queries for many-to-many relationship to search for unrelated tags

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I am working on an application that will do some sort of smart data search by disabling unrelated tags in a search pool.

For example (sorry if my formatting may be crappy), given this table:

```
    _id  |  _tagname
    1       A
    1       B
    1       C
    2       A
    2       B
    3       A
    4       B
    5       C
    6       D
```

when the user select tag **A**, (the following will be performed on *each* tag selection):

1. Fetch ID's that will match the tag -> **1, 2, 3** which will now be the new search pool
2. Hide all tags that will not be relevant -> **D** since tag **B** and **C** will allow the user to filter the tags to get ID **1**

**TL;DR**: This is my current approach and I was wondering if there are ways to optimize it because currently it is taking too long to get the results

```
SELECT _tagname FROM datatags WHERE 
(_tagname) NOT IN 
( SELECT _tagname FROM datatags WHERE 
_id IN (1,2,3)) 
GROUP BY _tagname
```

Thank you! This is my first time posting a question so please take it easy on me :)

*Edit: formatting*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you ultimately looking for the tags that appear together, or do you really want the odd tags out?

Here are two ways to find the related tags (returns `{ A, B, C }` for `A` or `B` or `C`, and returns `{ D }` for `D`)

- Use a correlated subquery:

  ```
  SELECT DISTINCT _tagname 
  FROM   datatags 
  WHERE  _id IN (SELECT _id 
                 FROM   datatags 
                 WHERE  _tagname = ?)
  ```
- Use a self join:

  ```
  SELECT DISTINCT b._tagname 
  FROM   datatags a 
         JOIN datatags b USING (_id) 
  WHERE  a._tagname = 'A'
  ```

For the inverse (tags that never appear with the given tag), you'd find the difference between the entire set of tags and the related tags. MySQL doesn't support `MINUS`, but here one way to find the unrelated tags:

- Use a correlated subquery with a self join:

  ```
  SELECT _tagname 
  FROM   datatags 
         LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT _tagname 
                    FROM   datatags 
                    WHERE  _id IN (SELECT _id 
                                   FROM   datatags 
                                   WHERE  _tagname = ?)) a USING (_tagname) 
  WHERE  a._tagname IS NULL
  ```

Comment: Ultimately, I just want to find the list of tags that are not going to be helpful in filtering out the current ID's. Since if the current results return ID's **1, 2, 3**, the tag **D** is totally irrelevant to further narrowed down the results, since none of **1, 2, 3** has the tag **D**. So I want to make sure tag **D** can be "suggested" as irrelevant.
Your answer looks like it might be fast, I shall try it and let you know!

Comment: it is about 8-9x faster (which is amazing) but given the size of my tables, it is still quite a bit long. But your suggestion help me form another solution. Thanks, so I will accept your answer :)

Comment: this is for the future to anyone who has similar problem:
since this is a many-to-many relationships, there is a table that hold the unique list of all available tags, so using user113215's suggestion, do a left join between the **tags** table and the **distinct** list of **_tagname**. Information on the **JOINS**:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins